# Linq to SQL - cross referencing two tables in one query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following scenario I need to accomplish via Linq to SQL:

I have a table called **JOBS** that contains these two columns:

- JobID
- JobName

I have another table called **JOBREFS** that contains these two columns:

- JobID
- JobRefID

I have the following query (I already have the JOBS.JobID)

Select JobRefID from JOBREFS where JOBREFS.JobID = JOBS.JobID

Then I need to do THIS query:

Select JobName from JOBS where JOBS.JobID = JOBREFS.JobRefID

I know I can do this in two queries, but thought there might be a way to get the JobName that is associated with the JobRefID in another table.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: `.. select new { JobRefID, JobName }` (or whatever) after the appropriate LINQ join.

Comment: Take a look at the [MSDN join clause examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If the navigation properties are correct in your models, you can just use those navigation properties instead of joins.  Some examples are here:

http://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Comment: Do navigation properties work in straight LINQ-to-SQL or do you have to be using Entity Framework?

Comment: I've never used it without EF, but I think you have to make sure your foreign keys are correct and specify the associations in your object model. I found this after a quick Google search, maybe you can find more examples by searching around. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386989(v=vs.110).aspx  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386932(v=vs.110).aspx